# Integration of Django based plug-ins into wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

Can anyone describe the general actions when integrating addons or widgets built originally for django in to wagtail? For a novice user, it's hard to understand exactly how to edit the code so that it works in wagtail cms.
For example, I'm trying to integrate two very useful Django addons(widgets) into my project and I encounter in both cases the problem, when it comes to customizing and inserting code into settings.py

In both cases i have to [customize](https://github.com/django-money/django-money#adding-a-new-currency) some [code](https://github.com/django-money/django-money#adding-a-new-currency) but we don't have settings.py in wagtail and if ill try to put this code:

```
COUNTRIES_OVERRIDE = {
   'XZ': _('Tibet')
}
```

in to base.py I'm getting an error:

```
(env) C:\Users\xakep\Documents\GitHub\database\blemmy>manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\xakep\Documents\GitHub\database\blemmy\manage.py", 
        line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
        line 363, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
        line 307, in execute settings.INSTALLED_APPS
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, 
        in__getattr__self._setup(name)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, 
        in _setup self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 110, 
        in__init__ mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in 
        _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in 
        _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\xakep\Documents\GitHub\database\blemmy\blemmy\settings\
        __init__.py", line 1, in <module> from .dev import *
    File "C:\Users\xakep\Documents\GitHub\database\blemmy\blemmy\settings\
        dev.py", line 2, in <module> from .base import *
    File "C:\Users\xakep\Documents\GitHub\database\blemmy\blemmy\settings\
        base.py", line 112, in <module> 'XZ': _('Tibet')
    NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

If you can help(explane) me how to use similar projects in wagtail i have tons of good ideas =)

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: what is the point of `_` ? I did not see that in docs.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries#customize-the-country-list) you can find the docs for this django app

Comment: My project should have countries that are not included in the standard ISO 3166-1, so i have to change(add) some code [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnaql.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base.py` is the correct location for settings like this. In the Wagtail project structure, the settings are split up into dev.py (for settings only used in the development environment), production.py (for settings only used in production), and base.py (common to both), as described here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/reference/project_template.html#django-settings

The `name '_' is not defined` error isn't related to Wagtail - it's a detail that's missing from the django-countries documentation. Defining a function called `_` is a standard convention for marking strings as translatable, described in the Django docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/

To fix it, add the following line to the top of your settings file:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Its works yet. @gasman
I will read this docs thank you +1